# Object.clone method call giving stack overflow error

Tags: java

Hey guys I'm having some trouble while trying to implement to clone() method in my code, here is the code in question

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab2B {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Octagon test = new Octagon();
      System.out.printf("The octagon has a side length of %1.2f, a perimiter of %1.2f, and an area of %1.2f.\n", test.sideLength, test.perimiter, test.area);
      Octagon clone = test.clone();
      System.out.println("Octagon cloned.");
      if (test.compareTo(test) == true)
      System.out.println("The octagons are identical");
      else
      System.out.println("The octagons are not identical");
   }
}

abstract class GeometricObject {
   double area;
   double perimiter;
}

class Octagon extends GeometricObject implements Comparable, Cloneable {
   double sideLength;
   public Octagon() {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter side length of Octagon: ");
      this.sideLength = input.nextDouble();
      this.area = ((2 + (4 / Math.sqrt(2))) * this.sideLength * this.sideLength);
      this.perimiter = (this.sideLength * 8);
   }
   public Octagon clone(){
      return this.clone();
   }
   public boolean compareTo(Octagon x) {
      if (this.sideLength == x.sideLength)
         if (this.perimiter == x.perimiter)
            if (this.area == this.area)
               return true;
            else
               return false;
         else
            return false;
      else
         return false;
   }
}
```

This is the console output I am getting,

```
Enter side length of Octagon: 
8
The octagon has a side length of 8.00, a perimiter of 64.00, and an area of 309.02.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Octagon.clone(Lab2B.java:32)
```

and it repeats the last line for a really long time... I'm still pretty new to java, and this is my first time trying to implement the clone method. From what I have seen so far online searching around I think I have everything I'm supposed to have but I'm really stumped on this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: "public Octagon clone(){
      return this.clone();
   }" The problem with that should be self-evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“return this.clone()”

in the clone method is a recursive call. Your function is calling itself and returning that value and this repeats into a stack overflow